# is it possible to use renjin within rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, renjin

I wanted to try out a faster version of R in Windows. pqR / Riposte do not have a Windows version. Renjin's website had a Renjin Studio GUI (for all platforms), which opens up a console where I can run R commands but that's not too useful. I understand that Renjin is still under development, but I want to ask: is it possible to use Renjin within RStudio, i.e. within RStudio set the "R Version" to Renjin?

Answer (score 3):

Not yet! RStudio is unfortunately but probably necessarily bound to specifically the GNU R shared library and GNU R's C API. Hacking together a quick fork of RStudio that talks to Renjin as a proof of concept is something that's probably a good weekend project, but unfortunately one among many good weekend projects...

Comment: Please let us know if/ when this integration will be ready :)

Comment: Glad your interested! Unfortunately it's not something that we're working on at the moment - though as a heavy R Studio user I would love to use Renjin for ad hoc analysis as well as on the server. Pull requests / sponsorships welcome!

Comment: Has this changed by now?

Comment: The one thing that you can do is load Renjin as a package within GNU R: http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/package/index.html

Comment: If you can do this in a weekend, I will eat my hat. Have you *seen* the RStudio codebase? It's a GWT UI talking to a C++ server linked against the GNU R C library. You'd either have to reimplement the server in Java maintaining compatibility with the GWT client, or wrap the C++ server with JNI. For those of you hoping for this feature, don't hold your breath ;)